# how to calculate the correct position of a mouse click

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a 2 programs:
one is a server -"The Controlled "
and the second one is a client -"The Controller "

Basically its a remote desktop program

The view from the Client is:
[image]

The red line is the PC window size.

The blue line is the program it self .

and the picturebox is maximized and set to be the same as the Program window size.

The picture that in side of it is getting re-sized so that it will fill the most of the picturebox but still stay in the same aspect ratio.

The sending protocol is :
Client dose all the calculations and sends the server the x and y of the mouse click
Server gets the x and y and click using them

the code i use to get the mouse position is:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetCursorPos(out MousePoint lpMousePoint);
```

One more thing - the server and the client sync their screen size

i was not able to get the mouse to click the needed spot at all (to many tries to tell)

The algorithm needs to be able to calculate the exact position the mouse clicked on the pic in relation to the server
example - i press on the X button on a window in the pictureBox - i need it to click on the same X button on the server side

The code for re-sizing that i use:

```
public Image resizeImage(int newWidth, int newHeight, Image imgPhoto)
    {


        int sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;

        //Consider vertical pics
        if (sourceWidth < sourceHeight)
        {
            int buff = newWidth;

            newWidth = newHeight;
            newHeight = buff;
        }

        int sourceX = 0, sourceY = 0, destX = 0, destY = 0;
        float nPercent = 0, nPercentW = 0, nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ((float)newWidth / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)newHeight / (float)sourceHeight);
        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
        {
            nPercent = nPercentH;
            destX = System.Convert.ToInt16((newWidth -
                      (sourceWidth * nPercent)) / 2);
        }
        else
        {
            nPercent = nPercentW;
            destY = System.Convert.ToInt16((newHeight -
                      (sourceHeight * nPercent)) / 2);
        }

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);


        Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight,
                      PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution,
                     imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

        Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
        grPhoto.Clear(Color.Black);
        grPhoto.InterpolationMode =
            InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto,
            new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
            new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight),
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        grPhoto.Dispose();
        imgPhoto.Dispose();
        return bmPhoto;
    }
```

as i understand my change resolution function is too complex

Comment: I don't know but your resizing seems to be too complex. And how can the aspect ratio be the same if you change the height and width in the beginning?

Comment: Does your resizing work as intended?

Comment: yes it dose , it work with no problem